# How to solve a connection refused to localhost error SQLCODE -902?

Tags: windows-8, firebird

Everyday for the past two weeks I've been successfully connecting to my Firebird database (2.0.1) with the isql prompt using the following connection string:

```
SQL> CONNECT "localhost:C:\Users\casa\Desktop\DB-Helper\PDVDATA.FDB" user 'SYSDB
A' password 'masterkey';
```

Today I couldn't. Instead I'm getting this error:

```
Statement failed, SQLCODE = -902
Unable to complete network request to host "localhost".
-Failed to establish a connection.
-No se puede establecer una conexi¾n ya que el equipo de destino deneg¾ expresam
ente dicha conexi¾n.
```

The last line can be translate to:
can't establish a connection because the end machine expressly rejected such connection (sorry I did my best here :S)

The only thing I can think is different today, is that yesterday, when turning off the computer I was prompted to update (I'm using Windows 8). Besides that I'm not doing nor did I install anything new.

I tried fixing the issue with:
opened windows firewall advanced security and created both inbound and outbound rule > for a port > TCP 3050 > allow connection > Domain, private and public > name: gds_db no description

I've also run in a command prompt

```
telnet localhost 3050
```

and the response was:

```
Conectándose a localhost...No se puede abrir la conexión al host, en puerto 3050
: Error en la conexión
```

Which can translate to:
Connecting to localhost... Can't open the connection to host on port 3050: error in the connection

To be fair I've also tried the same thing (telnet localhost 3050) on a different PC, with a different OS (Ubuntu) with a different ISP and got the same response.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've just tried disabling the firewall alltogether... and that didn't help :(

Comment: It sounds like your Firebird server is not running.

Comment: Also, why are you running Firebird 2.0.1?! not only is Firebird 2.0 out of support for more than 16 years, Firebird 2.0.1 is not even the latest Firebird 2.0 (that is Firebird 2.0.7). Current supported versions are Firebird 3.0 and 4.0, or otherwise at least Firebird 2.5.9 (which can open Firebird 2.0 databases, while Firebird 3.0 and higher requires a backup and restore).

Comment: The file I need to manipulate is 2.0.1, I'm using the server 2.0.7 cause it's the only one compatible with that file version. I did try connecting using the server version 2.5, and 4 but I couldn't access that file. You said server 2.5 would open 2.0 files? are you sure about that I did try and was getting an error. Maybe I'm mistaken. Thanks for your comments :) I appreciate all the help I could get.

Comment: Firebird 2.5 can open all database files from Firebird 1.0 and higher. However, for Firebird 2.0 and earlier (IIRC), if the database was created with a 32-bit Firebird server, you need a 32-bit Firebird server to read it. Alternatively, back it up under Firebird 2.0 and restore it under a newer version to upgrade the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark Rotteveel was right!

> It sounds like your Firebird server is not running. – 
> Mark Rotteveel

I run

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Firebird\Firebird_2_0\bin>instsvc start
```

and that started the service. After that the connection was made like usual.
Idiot me I choose the 'start the service manually' during the installation.
I wasn't lying though for the past two weeks I did started the connection in the isql without starting the service manually.
I forgot I choose that configuration. It was driving me insane!
Thanks a lot Mark :)